# getLastKnownLocation() does not necessarily give current location

Tags: android, gps, location

looks like when getLastKnownLocation() is called it gives the location of the last time this provider was available, i'm using the GPS provider and i want it to return null if location is not yet set by GPS.
so basically i would like any of the following:

- how to reset location of GPS (so when getLastKnownLocation() is called it gives null)

or

- how see if GPS location is set

any help is appreciated ... Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [android getBestProvider never returns gps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480042/android-getbestprovider-never-returns-gps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried requesting permission to the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` provider in your manifest and then from the LocationManager, calling getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)?
It should return to you the last known location acquired by the GPS provider, else null if it can't get the location

Comment: well that's exactly my problem, i dont want it to get the last known location i want it to get the current location (i.e either GPS has made a fix or null)

Comment: If you're not satisfied with the location that was stored the last time the location provider determined it's location then you need to register a callback either with requestLocationUpdates in the case where you want to keep receiving updates every time the provider is refreshed or else requestSingleUpdate which will give you an update the next time the provider refreshes itself

Comment: the problem is that i want to know IF the location is set right now, if not, i don't want it to return the last known location, i want it to return null.

Comment: The API doesn't support that, but you could use getTime() to find out when the last fix was, and it would be up to your determination if the fix is stale and you want to register a callback to get the next one

Comment: for future references, i was able to solve that using LocationManager.requestLocatioUpdates()

Comment: looks like i didn't catch your drift, my bad, thank you very much

Comment: i do have a question though, does the onLocationChanged() gets fired up every time my location change, because i made a code inside it to move the camera depending on my location (the blue dot) and the dot changes but the camera doesn't ??

Comment: That really depends on which version of requestLocationUpdates() that you called.  You can specify a minimum amount of time that you want to elapse before you get another update, or a minimum about of distance between updates, and also what Criteria you used.  Just changing location won't kick off the callback, you have to exceed one of those thresholds before you'll be alerted that location changed

Comment: ok i get it now, thank you very much and sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Can you mark your question as resolved so others won't attempt to answer it?  No inconvenience at all.