# Android getBestProvider never returns GPS

Tags: android, location, location-provider

I have been working on a location based app.

I am testing on both `Samsung Galaxy S4` and `Samsung Tab 7`.

When calling `getBestProvider()` it usually returns GPS if it was enabled and network otherwise, and that was the case on my Galaxy S4.

However, when I tried to run the application on the tab, the GPS provider was never returned by `getBestProvider()` even when it was enabled.

The S4 has android `4.2.2` while the tab has `4.1.1`, could that be the problem, if not, what is?

Comment: samsung phones have a inherent issue, they dont port google as correctly as expected. Unfortunately they dont have a bugs area to for developers like us to log bugs. And google wont let us log samsung bugs, since samsung customizes android for their phones unlike HTC.

Comment: do this experiment, run your code on you any device other than samsung, HTC. It will work like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of what provider you use GPS, NETWORK or best, all work on the same principle of getting the location from a local (on the device) cache.

If you want GPS instantly you need to hack the system to update the cache and then read it. On Samsung phones this hack is needed. On HTC and other models you dont need this hack. 
I (fortunately) have found the way to trigger that cache update with a hack.

Just call the following code before your getLastKnownLocation.

```
<YourActivity>.getLocationManager().requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
            @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    }
});
```

OR

Use LocationClient. The new API's (just in) for location updates. These API's dont need you to find the best provider instead do all this shit underneath.

Comment: thank you, but i have a question (could be a stupid one), but what exactly is HomeScreen?

also, should i write this code even though i have my own implementation of requestLocationUpdates?

Comment: it says that getLocationManager() is undefined !!

Comment: I googled for "getLocationManger" and got http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/ and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html and many more. I suggest you read up some sites and help from google. Its easy to get through.

Comment: thank you very much, appreciate the help :)

about the whole samsung GPS bug, is it alright to publish the app without handling it ??

Comment: you are welcome. Please pass on the appreciation in a way that I can be encouraged too. No upvote or no accept is discouraging.\

Comment: Hi Siddharth , how to handle GPS problem in samsung devices .

Comment: Use network provider only. Use full Wake Lock and the code to reset the locationprovider.

Answer (score 1):

getBestProvider() won't always return GPS. Because GPS is not always the best provider. Is the tab connected to wifi? Location from wifi is quite accurate so that may be returned if you are connected to wifi.

Also, you should switch to the new Location service which is part of Google Play Services. Using the fuse location provider will take all the hassle out of managing the providers and give you the best result.

Comment: the thing is, even when i force the location to get the location based on the GPS provider, i get no signal !!!

and i have no idea what the new location service is, can you please provide some sort of links or tutorials, thnQ

Comment: @Siddharth thank you very much, but won't that be considered as a  problem when users with samsung devices download my app.

also, why didn't this happen on my samsung S4

Comment: You should post this question on samsung forums. I wont have a answer.

Comment: Here's a link to the Google Play Services Location Api's https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

And 

And a few videos from google io this year which explains it a little:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49pWckcaZEI&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9WGUwq2gQ-coU3fSyexgOx&index=2

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9WGUwq2gQ-coU3fSyexgOx&index=6